# Setting up dasblog as virtual directory under Umbraco application

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, umbraco, virtual-directory, dasblog

I have created an application using Umbraco CMS, with .net framework 4.0 and hosting in IIS6. I have developed a blog for the application using dasblog (.net frame work 2.0)

I need to set the blog as virtual directory under the main application and I am not able to set due to some inheritance.

If I enter the below in parent application web-config, the main application throws 500 server error: inheritInChildApplications="false"

Let me know what other options I could try and set this up.

Expecting an answer at the earliest as I would need to set up the application at the earliest due to its urgency.

Thanks and Regards,
Alex Varghese

---

Thanks for the suggestion, When i setup the same environment on Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7, without mentioning the inheritance tag in my parent application, i receive the below error.
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Config Error: the configuration section 'system.web.extensions' cannot be read because it is missing a section. 
I didnt add no inheritance tag because my parent application is built using .Net framework 4.0 and blog as child application is using 2.0  framework.

Even, If i would add  inheritInChildApplications in parent application like below:

```
<location inheritInChildApplications="false">
<system.web>
</system.web>
</location>
```

I received the same Internal Server Error, I strongly belive this might be because of inheritance or .net framework versions behavior on this server.

Please explain, how should i narrow down this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to give more detail in order to for anybody to be able to help you. For example, what's your intent with setting `inheritInChildApplications`? What exactly is the error that you see when you set this?
I suspect you're trying to be able to browse to the directory that you're trying to install dasBlog to and are having issue with Umbraco not finding anything there, thus returning a 404. -Are you familiar with  `umbracoReservedPaths` under appsettings? Define your path you wish to exclude here so that your application will not battle umbraco url aliasing.

You might check this link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Umbraco/FAQ#Installation as it mentions issues with (umbraco under) virtual directories. Again, it's difficult with the little info we have to work with here.
If non of the above helps, you may check that you have .net4.0 installed. Not sure how well IIS6 will work at this point.. good luck? 
I'll try and watch for updates if you add more info;)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was kind of resolved after making necessary changes in parent config file to avoid  inheritance.

We were successfully set the application in IIS 7. But in IIS 6, we experienced a new error. Below is the description:

Main Website (Umbraco Commerce website with .net framework 4.0 ) - Loading fine

Blog as virtual directory ( Dasblog with .net framework 2.0)

Main Website is working fine.
Blog is throwing an error - Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: /blog/eurl.axd/03d1dd7c74ca7844a5e248706fc9d544
Troubleshooting which I have done: 1. When you access blog/default.aspx, the blog loads fine. (Default doc is already added in IIS) 2. In Registry added a DWORD with value= 0 in ASP.net 2.0 (Not working) 3. Added DWORD in Asp.net 4.0 with value = 0 (main application stopped working and Blog started working.

Let me know your comments regarding the same.

The issue is in IIS 6. IIS 7 works fine.

Any help from you at the earliest is much appreciated.

Regards, Alex